# iOS: should my app only be released in local App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an iOS application which I targeted for Danish users. The UI language is English or Danish, but the news content is Danish -- this is the main part of its functionality.
The first day the app was released, the app was downloaded about 80 times, but only 5% was users from the Danish App Store.

For fear of bad ratings, wouldn't it be reasonable to change the app only to be released in the Danish App Store?

Comment: Possibly better for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's clear (in the app description) that the app is targeted mainly at speakers of the Danish language, I can't imagine why people would leave bad ratings because of your concerns above. Then again, people leave bad ratings just because they *can*, so you might have a point.  Danish users probably use the English app store more than the Danish one, out of habit, since proportionately fewer apps are available **AND** localized for the Danish language.